# View existing indexes using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin, is it possible to view existing indexes on a table?  If so,how?  One of my tables should have an unique index with two keys, and I want to confirm it exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it is. You have to get into the database, select the table and then go to **Structure** tab. Below the columns definitions is the list of indexes for the table.

Comment: Thank you.  I must be blind.  I expected I would see it in the structure tab, yet I do not see any indexes.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  I must click the Indexes link!

Comment: Indexes are always in the Stucture tab but their position varies with different phpMyAdmin versions and themes.

Answer (score 4):

At the structure tab, bellow the columns there is a link `indexes`, just click there and another table will show all the indexes related.